# How do I set an og:type for the first time without losing likes?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I first created my site, I neglected to add the Open Graph tags that Facebook recommends (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/), and the site now has about 1200 Facebook likes through a fb:comments widget. http://graph.facebook.com/http://feedtheanimalssamples.com/ shows this:

```
{
   "id": "http://feedtheanimalssamples.com/",
   "shares": 1204
}
```

Recently, I've added added the following OG tags:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="59193243341" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Girl Talk - Feed The Animals Samples (old)" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://feedtheanimalssamples.com/fta_small.png" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://feedtheanimalssamples.com" />
```

But when I add the og:type tag:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
```

and Lint the site, I lose all my likes. http://graph.facebook.com/http://feedtheanimalssamples.com/ starts showing this:

```
{
   "id": "170545342993850",
   "name": "Girl Talk - Feed The Animals Samples",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/188039_170545342993850_3277642_s.jpg",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/pages/Girl-Talk-Feed-The-Animals-Samples/170545342993850",
   "category": "Website",
   "website": "http://feedtheanimalssamples.com/",
   "description": "Interactively identifies the samples in the 2008 album 'Feed The Animals' by mashup artist Girl Talk.",
   "likes": 1
}
```

(Note the "likes": 1.)

So: How do I set the og:type without losing my likes?

I'm trying to let my likers know that I've created a new and improved site. I'm following the instuctions at http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/397 under "Publishing to Connected Users via Graph API", but using that API apparently requires specifying an og:type.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer to this, but it looks like they mention this in their platform update on Friday, November 19, 2010:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/430/

> Ability to change Open Graph types
>
> Based on feedback from developers,
> we now allow sites to change Open Graph objects types (og:type) until
> they receive 10,000 likes. This will not reset like counts. We
> encourage developers use this opportunity to add or correct their Open
> Graph object types so they will be accurately represented in the
> future.

But looking at the chronology, your post was after this change, so perhaps it was only temporary.

Answer (score -1):

Also provide `og:site_name` with your site name, as it is also required.

Comment: Yes, according to the [docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/), it's required, but adding it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Just for kicks, what happens if you use a different type, like article or album? Does anything change?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not positive, but you may need to "Migrate" your Like Button.

See [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/migration/) developer page.

...which has this quote:

> For existing Like Buttons, previous counts will be maintained with the migration. The migration will not affect Like counts and the expected functionality of the Like Button except certain features as outlined in the previous section.

I still don't quite understand the whole migration yet, myself, but it may help you.